# For OpenAI's gym, is it possible to render without using the gym step function?

Tags: rendering, openai-gym, openai-api

In simulating a trajectory for a OpenAI gym environment, such as the Mujoco Walker2d, one feeds the current observation and action into the gym step function to produce the next observation. However, there appears to be no way render a given trajectory of observations only (this is all it needs for rendering)! Does anyone know how to do this, or if it is even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `env.render`

Example:

```py
for state in trajectory:
    env.unwrapped.state = state
    env.render()
```